# Email notifications are not being sent on custom mass order status change

Tags: adminhtml, order-status

I’m working on a custom Magento extension that performs mass updates on order status, however it is not sending the customer an email when their order is updated.

[image]

### Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <masscustomstatusses>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses</module>
                    <frontName>masscustomstatusses</frontName>
                </args>
            </masscustomstatusses>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>   
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <sales> 
            <order> 
                <states>
                    <masscustom1 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 1</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom1 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom1>
                    <masscustom2 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 2</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom2 default="2"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>2</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom2>
                    <masscustom3 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 3</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom3 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom3>
                    <masscustom4 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 4</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom4 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom4>
                    <masscustom5 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 5</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom5 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom5>
                    <masscustom6 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 6</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom6 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom6>
                    <masscustom7 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 7</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom7 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom7>
                    <masscustom8 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 8</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom8 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom8>
                    <masscustom9 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 9</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom9 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom9>
                    <masscustom10 translate="label">
                        <label>Mass Custom Action 10</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <masscustom10 default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </masscustom10>         
                </states>
            </order>
        </sales>    
    </global>
</config>
```

### Controller

Here’s the method of the controller for mass order status changes:

```
public function NewMass1Action()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
    $countHoldOrder = 0;

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        if ($order->canHold()) {
            $order->masscustom1()->save();
            $countHoldOrder++;
        }
    }

    if ($countHoldOrder) {
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('%s order(s) have changed status.', $countHoldOrder));
    }

    $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/index'));
}
```

### Model

Here is the method it calls for updating the order status:

```
public function masscustom1()
{
    $this->setMasscustom1BeforeState($this->getState());
    $this->setMasscustom1BeforeStatus($this->getStatus());
    $this->setState(self::STATE_MASSCUSTOM1, true);
    $orderId = isset($_POST['orderid']) ? $_POST['orderid'] : null;
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $comment = '';
    $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, $comment);
    return $this;
}
```

Here is what happens when I view an order whose status I changed by this method:

[image]

So, can you guys help me fix the problem and make this method send emails for the order status changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to load the order again inside of `masscustom1()` since it is a method of the `VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_Model_Order` class that is extending `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`. That means you are already working with an order object instance and that its methods should be invoked using `$this`.

You can just remove this part:

```
$orderId = isset($_POST['orderid']) ? $_POST['orderid'] : null;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

And call the method on `$this` instead:

```
$comment = 'testing';
$this->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, $comment)
```

Comment: I did what you recommend and now it says - `Customer Notified` instead of `Customer Notification Not Applicable` but it is not sending any emails again. So i still have the same problem. Also i you are right about the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`. Any other advice?

Comment: Fantastico! It is working!