# How to send email on order status change

Tags: php

i'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

I've created a function for mass order status change.

Here is my code:

```
public function NewMass1Action()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
    $countHoldOrder = 0;

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        if ($order->canHold()) {
            $order->masscustom1()
                ->save();
            $countHoldOrder++;
        }
    }

    if ($countHoldOrder) {
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('%s order(s) have changed status.', $countHoldOrder));
    }

    $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/index'));
}
```

The problem is that this function is not sending an email to the customer when his order status is changed.

How can i make this function send an email for the status change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors reporting?

Comment: No errors, everything is working okey but it is not sending any emails.

Comment: Hmmm... Did you check your email server for possible errors as well?
PEPEKA!@!

Comment: This question has been [merged with its followup question, and includes the final solution there](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/61606/20131).